# Authenticating with Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET WebAPI for a web service that I am building. He web service will use the Identity service to authenticate users.

I am a bit stuck as to how to authenticate users externally. Our current system is very basic- we send a username and password in the XML request as a separate field and it is all done in 1 request.

From what I can see from looking on Google, the best way is to request a token from the Ali and then pass this token in subsequent requests. Is there a way where I can do it all in 1 request (that is, send to the API my request for data as well as the username/password or perhaps an API key in a single request?)

Answer (score 0):

> From what I can see from looking on Google, the best way is to request
>   a token from the Ali and then pass this token in subsequent requests.
>   Is there a way where I can do it all in 1 request (that is, send to
>   the API my request for data as well as the username/password or
>   perhaps an API key in a single request?)

I'm not sure why your web service want to know user's username and password in Token based Authentication.

**In Token based Authentication, your web service should not ask for user's username and password.**

Instead, user first verifies the user name and password using **a token issuer that your service trusts**.

Upon successful verification, the token issuer provides the user with a token. Once the user has that token, it uses it to call your service.

For that, you do not have to reinvent the wheel. Here is [JwtAuthForWebAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JwtAuthForWebAPI) nuget package for OAuth2 and OpenId Connect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not secure at all to keep sending username/password with each request, you need to configure your api to issue access tokens for specified life time i.e. 24 hours. To do so you need create and end point (/token) which accepts the username/password validate the combination then issue an access token.
The client which receives this access token is responsible to store is securely and transmit it with each request to an any protected resource using the request "Authorization" header using bearer scheme.

As well you can not do this in one request, you need to obtain the access token at the beginning the you keep calling your protected resources using this access token until it is expired.

You can read more about this in my detailed blog post about [Token Based Authentication in Web API](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)